# Optimal control problem for nonlinear harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, reference-request, control-theory, optimal-control

Given $\bar x \in \mathbb R$, minimize

$$ J(u) = \int_0^T  |x(t) - \bar x|^2 \,{\rm d} t + \int_0^T u^2(t) \,{\rm d} t $$

where $x(t)$ solves the following ODE

$$ x''(t) + \sin (x(t)) = u(t) $$

with initial conditions $x(0) = x_0$ and $x'(0)= x_1$, can you point out a reference where the existence (and uniqueness?) of a minimizer and the first-order optimality conditions are analyzed in detail?

---

I know some resources for the linearized harmonic oscillator $x''(t) + x(t) = u(t)$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, exactly: an harmonic oscillator

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Ok

Comment: Lawrence C. Evans, [An Introduction to Mathematical Optimal Control Theory](https://math.berkeley.edu/~evans/control.course.pdf), Department of Mathematics, University of California, Berkeley.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Where is the nonlinear pendulum in these notes?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I see the linear one.